How do I use the current version of the GDPR form to request a data export?
Previously, in 2019, in this answer a process of requesting a dump of your export was documented. Since then, the design of the site was changed, and the current data request form isn't very clear about what things do. There's also another post requesting for a comprehensive explanation of what things do.
How do I get a GDPR data request to export my data with the current system, and what's the correct option to pick?
There's an option called data portability, but It isn't clear if that's the same as the export my data, and this should be documented in a usable way here.
Practically, I don't need a export now - but the GDPR export include a bunch of useful things, like chat logs. It would be nice if this wasn't, to quote Douglas Adams, "on display in the bottom of a locked filing cabinet stuck in a disused lavatory with a sign on the door saying ‘Beware of the Leopard’.”

I THINK this should be covered by either Data Portability (probably the correct option based on the GDPR laws) or Access (based on the strange additional choice you get if you pick that option). In doubt... use both so that they can't step down from your request. They left a free text field so use that to add any detail that will make your request clear and unambiguous (even in bad faith)

them stepping down/refusing is a useful data point. I've included that I wanted a dump in order to document the data dump process, as per this question with a link, cause I'm nice like that. If the data portability option dosen't work then I might try access.

Technically, I think they CAN'T step down since I remember reading that they have to give a reasonable answer even if the requestor refused to further restrict the scope of their request, yet that doesn't mean I don't expect them to TRY, thinking they won't face any consequences.

You repeatedly refer to "dumps" of your data – you may want to rephrase this to "exports" of your data instead – just to avoid confusion with the actual data dumps of all data on the site/network.

That's true, I've edited it to reflect

tldr: Its a really convoluted process compared to the previously documented one.  Took close to a day in total.
As of 2024 this is what the form looks like

Clicking on the select data types brings up a dropdown, and selecting one or more options puts a button below the dropdown

I think data portability is the correct option?

The other bit of ambiguity is what type of user we are

I went with consumer.
You will get an email with a link to confirm.

This VERY helpfully starts with the name you supplied, then proceeds to obfuscate the same name in the body.

I've gotten the next set of emails

This one asks me to confirm that I made a request and intend to proceed

Which leads me to here, which tells me they got my request and will process it
And I get another email asking me to access the portal to access my request

Which then leads me to a page asking me to give my email again requesting an access code


Yup. Another page, and practically this hasn't actually gotten me the data exports yet.

And finally!


And what exactly was included in the download may I ask?

https://i.sstatic.net/ZLzDpKLm.png  I'll need to give it a read through before I can go into any more detail

Lovely. Based on the folders name, it should be possible to get a full data dump by joining up the personal data dumps. I wonder if they really want to push users to do that...

there's a bunch of PII - IP addresses and such, and some of the data probably needs more context to make sense. I mean, I guess one could write a sanitation tool, but you'd need EVERYONE's personal dumps and a way to assemble it.

The company would have self combusted far before you got enough dumps. It would be no different from a DDOS

So basically impossible. Its probably good enough if you wanted your own content, and had the skills to convert from JSON to something more digestable
